# Login Logout authentication and uploading views and pics in our applcation

Tags: iphone, ios, authentication

I want to create an application in which i want a login logout authentication from the database file that can be handled by web services. This application should always need to be connected with the internet and after login i need to upload images and also give there views about the image and i am not getting any idea how start work on that can anyone help me.... I want to use this application some sort similar like facebook.

There is also a problem that which type of application i create native or web or else. Please help me to start this application.....

Comment: Your question itself is quite unclear,please re-edit it to make it more understanding..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting up a server that can handle the requests from your app. Your app can then request content or upload content to the server using NSURLRequest. For further reading refer http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/URLOverview.html

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking the wrong question. What web development language do you know to help you accomplish this? There are many different ways to go, like open source as opposed to paid, which services best handle your specific needs, like Ruby or PHP, which RDBMS to use, etc. If you don't know any programming, then it is going to be a long road. Your first step should be taking what you already know and branching from there, learning what you need to know. In your case, you'll need to learn server side scripting, connect it with a database, how to set up a server to put it all in, as well as client side development like javascript to go with the html.